# Group information at many rows but the same column to the one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me with this problem? I have a one table which records measuring data with information related to the ParentID. Unfortunately, each measuring data are written into one column (identified by value of previous columns). I would like to read all values from this column and write it into one row but different columns to have one row about each measuring. Combinations of TagID and Instance values can be 21. So I need in the result 21 columns with value in one row (M1....M21).
Running on SQL server 2016.

Source table:

| ParentID | TagID | Instance | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 14 | 2010 | 117.42 |
| AA | 18 | 3020 | 0.345 |
| AA | 16 | 2010 | 1.1234 |
| BB | 17 | 2016 | 12.1234 |
| BB | 09 | 0 | 0.0123 |

Requested table:

| ParentID | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA |  | 117.42 |  | 1.1234 |  | 0.345 |
| BB | 0.0123 |  | 12.1234 |  |  |  |

Empty columns could be 0 or rather NULL.

EDIT - another column in
Source table:

| ParentID | TagID | Instance | Data | DataText |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 14 | 2010 | 117.42 |  |
| AA | 18 | 3020 | 0.345 |  |
| AA | 12 | 1000 |  | Text1 |
| BB | 11 | 1010 |  | Text2 |
| AA | 16 | 2010 | 1.1234 |  |
| BB | 17 | 2016 | 12.1234 |  |
| BB | 09 | 0 | 0.0123 |  |

Requested table:

| ParentID | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M6 | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA |  | 117.42 |  | 1.1234 |  | 0.345 | Text1 |
| BB | 0.0123 |  | 12.1234 |  |  |  | Text2 |

Comment: search for `PIVOT`

Comment: Or, alternatively, "conditional aggregation" (which many prefer over the restrictive `PIVOT` operator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) query like below

```
select ParentID, [14-2010] [M1], [18-3020] [M2],[16-2010] [M3]
from
(
select 
 ParentID, 
 CAST(TagID as NVARCHAR) + "-" +CAST(Instance AS NVARCHAR) as pivotcol,
 Data
from your table )src
PIVOT( MAX(Data) FOR pivotcol in ([14-2010],[18-3020],[16-2010]))p
```

I intentionally went upto M3. in your use case feel free to add unique combinations of tagid and instance inside the pivot in sub query part and in the top select part.

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thank you! Please, can I add data from another columns in source table? For instance from column DatText? Column DataText is nvarchar.

Comment: What ever you add to inner query src can be bubbled up right to top outer query. So yes!

Comment: @Jay if you found my answer helpful, please upvote and consider accepting it as the correct answer for closure so that future readers will find it helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a next column 'DataText' to the src query will this column with the first value...not as the 'Data' column spread to [Mxx] values. Please can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: Example added to the origin question.

Comment: @Jay That's the thing you should not mix data types when pivoting. See this fiddle for possibly what you want https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc05a7e44b04c801024088688035bbd1

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately it is working only when one value is in the DataText column. When add more values, still MAX value displayed. Pls see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35548f744e3187220da7742bfd7b485a

Comment: @Jay I'd suggest create a separate question and also provide clarity on what is the expected output as per the input in the above fiddle